# API Gateway request API Limitation Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, limit, google-cloud-run, quota, google-cloud-api-gateway

Can I limit my API Gateway request limitation?

For example
URL A with path like this :

`aaaaaaaa.com/predict`

I set URL A only can be requested 1000 per day and the same URL with another path like this :

`aaaaaaaa.com/calling`

`/calling` only can be requested 500 per day

So, can I set a path with a limited request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/rate-limit-your-api-usage-with-cloud-endpoints-quotas-1270da55d2bf) with Cloud Endpoint and it's the same thing with API Gateway (simply a managed version of Cloud Endpoint).

If you want to limit the requests per day AND per requester, you need to add API keys to differentiate all the requesters. And the requester need to use it to indicate in which quota the request if counted.

Take care, an API identify a project. If you have several requesters, you need several API keys, each one in a different project. Else, if you put all in the same project, it's the same project which will be identified, and thus the same quota decreased.

Comment: Thank you! can I set the limitation requester with a different API Key? like key A only 500 request, key B 1000 request? from what I see from your code it looks like set it for all API keys? or limitation on each API Key only available on API Management such as apigee ?

Comment: No, you can't, the limit is only per API endpoint. You haven't the capacity to set limits on specific keys. You need to implement something on your side or use more advanced solutions (and more expensive) such as Apigee.